# Error while installing jQuery in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack

I want to use jquery in my TypeScript project (not Angular2+/Angular). But I am getting the following error:

ERROR in ./main.ts
(1,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.
webpack: Failed to compile.

I tried every possible solution and it is still throwing an error. What I can do to resolve this?

I have installed @types, @types/jquery, I also upgraded my TypeScript and jQuery, all from NPM.

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "npm-ts-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2019.2.619",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/kendo-ui": "^2019.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.39.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

main.ts file:

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery';

//jQuery code
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "./bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

I want to use jQuery in my TypeScript project without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
```

Comment: I tried that. But I got the following error:


(1,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.
webpack: Failed to compile.

npm ERR! npm-ts-example@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --inline --open`

Comment: Can you try to run `webpack-dev-server` only ?

Comment: It asked me to install webpack-cli: The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI. I did that and now it says: ReferenceError: webpack is not defined

Comment: I did that but still got an error. But I found the issue. I updated the ts-loader version and changed my module in webpack.config.js

Thank you so much for your help